# Google autocomplete place API not suggesting few popular places

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am using **https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocompete?key=MyKey&input=MySearchText api** for auto place suggestion , but I am not getting few popular cities in response and the same place I can easily search on google map application. Can anyone please help me on this what I am doing wrong and what can be the reason google place api is not suggesting this location? I am searching for below location : 
4 horner square london e1 6ew

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

When I search the '4 horner square london e1 6ew' with Geocoding API I can get this address.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=4%20horner%20square%20london%20e1%206ew&key=YOUR_API_KEY

The place ID is ChIJs2foBLQcdkgRHljoVNXS89g

The fact that this place doesn't appear in Place autocomplete is really weird. I also have ZERO_RESULTS:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=4%20horner%20square%20london%20e1%206ew&key=YOUR_API_KEY

I think you have to file an issue in the public [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/).